# NSMutableArray inside NSMutableArray Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to store NSMutableArray inside NSMutableArray.
So

```
var all:NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()
let localArray:NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()
var i = 0
for ..........{

    /* Add objects to localArray */
    localArray.addObject("1\(i)")
    /* Add localArray to all Array */
    all.addObject(localArray)
    /* Reset the array after adding to `all` array */
    localArray.removeAllObjects() 
    i+=1
}
```

**But** the result: variable ***all*** which is **NSMutableArray** is reseted.

Comment: You are adding multiple references in `all` to one array and emptying it each time through the loop.  Try `print(all)` when you exit the loop to see what's happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike Swift's native arrays (which are `struct`s and thus value types), `NSMutableArray`s are objects (reference types).  By clearing out the mutable array after adding it to the other array, you are clearing out the only copy of that object.

If you move the declaration of `localArray` to inside your loop, you will get a new instance of the array each time through the loop and you will achieve the behavior you are looking for:

```
let all = NSMutableArray()
var i = 0
for ..........{
    let localArray = NSMutableArray()

    /* Add objects to localArray */
    localArray.addObject("1\(i)")
    /* Add localArray to all Array */
    all.addObject(localArray)

    i += 1
}
```

Note that I have removed the code which clears out `localArray` because that is no longer necessary since you get a new array each time through the loop.

Comment: Use of explicit types are not recommended, better to use implicit: `var all = NSMutableArray()`. Also unlike Swift Arrays in NSMutableArray the value of the object doesn't get modified, so `all` can be a `let`variable.

Comment: Thanks @VladimirNul, I made those changes to the code.

Answer (score -1):

```
var all:NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()
var i = 0
for ..........{
    let localArray:NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()    
    /* Add objects to localArray */
    localArray.addObject("1\(i)")
    all.addObject(localArray)
    localArray.removeAllObjects() /* To reset the array after adding to  `all` array*/
    i+=1
}
```

but i would recommend to use Swift Array

like so

```
var all = Array<Array<Type>>()
```

Comment: @TestO.  Don't "reset" the inner array.  You're storing a reference to it inside `all`, not a copy.  That means anything you do to it after storing the reference applies to what's inside `all` too.